# discord.py - delete guild from json after bot leaves server

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make my bot public and therefore I need to store several IDs in a json.

If the bot joins a guild, it will create an entry in json:

```json
{
    "token": "MY_TOKEN",
    "guilds": {
        "TiLiKas": {
            "rules_message": {
                "rules_id": 780729484931366912
            },
            "ticket_message": {
                "ticket_id": 778567282321391638
            }
        },
        "Darkness": {
            "rules_message": {
                "rules_id": 765132820049428481
            },
            "ticket_message": {
                "ticket_id": 798839023031549962
            }
        },
        "Bot-Test-Server": {
            "rules_message": {},
            "ticket_message": {}
        }
    }
}
```

How I create the guild information:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_join(self, ctx):

    default_prefix = "?"

    for guild in self.client.guilds:

        guildName = guild

    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

        tmpDict = {
            "rules_message": { },
            "ticket_message": { }
        }

        data["guilds"][str(guildName)] = tmpDict

        with open("data.json", "w") as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

The problem is, if the bot gets kicked from the server, the entry remains in the json.

**How can I delete the server from json if the bot leaves the guild?**

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Think about it, there's an `on_guild_join` event, so there is a `on_guild_remove` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, there is an `on_guild_remove` event, you can delete the guild from the json file there

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_guild_remove(self, guild):
    with open("data.json", "r") as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    del data["guild"][str(guild)]
 
    with open("data.json", "w") as f:
        json.dump(data, f, indent=2)
```

#### Reference:

- [`on_guild_remove`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_remove)

Comment: Okay, I was just thinking too complicated. I have tried to compare ``self.client.guilds`` with the entries in ``data["guilds"]``. But now everything works, thank you :)